# Copy of an hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, clone

I have an `Hashmap <integer, Arraylist<Double>>`. I would like to make a copy of it. I was thinking of using  method `clone` of hashmap. After going through the javadoc, it 
says the following:

```
clone
Returns a shallow copy of this HashMap instance: the keys and values themselves are not cloned.
```

What does this shallow copy means? I want a separate matrix , whose values does not change while updating the value of original matrix.

Moreover why does,

```
    if( hm1 == hm1.clone())
```

returns false?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shallow copy means that only the map object is created new, but its values are not cloned, i.e. the copy contains references to the old entries. So to "deep clone" a map you would need to do:

1. create a new hash map object
2. iterate over all entries in the old map and add the **(deep) clones** of the key and value to the new map

Because `==` compares the object reference, not the content of the map.

Comment: Doesnt shallow copy means that the original and the copy are actually allocated at the same address? That means if you change the value of one, the other one will be changed too? (for c++)

Comment: @phantasmagoria No, in Java that would just be two pointers to the same instance.

Comment: @Baqueta Ok, 2 pointers pointing to one instance. Therefore changing one will cause the other one to change actually right? (You have started with "No" but we are talking about the same thing I suppose.)

Comment: @Baqueta No, it means the `clone()` method will create a completely new `HashMap` object allocated at a new address. After that it just sets the references to the entry tables in the newly created map to the one from the old map

Comment: i just tested, the change in either of the matrix(original or clone) makes effect in both of the matrices. If we have large matrix, then cloning for every new iteration seems inefficient. is there any way to to it efficiently?

Comment: @thetna Of course the change is visible in both versions. It's because the values of the map are not cloned. I.e. both maps refer to/share the same entries. Without seeing some code it is difficult to say if there are better options than cloning

Comment: @phantasmagoria: Sorry for the confusion. I meant that what you were describing is NOT a cloned object in Java. What you described is just two pointers to the same instance.

Comment: @hage: I wasn't disagreeing with you! My comment was directed at phantasmagoria!

Answer (score 0):

Map has keys (Integer instances in your case) and values (ArrayLists). IN the cloned map all the keys and values will be the same instances.

E.g. you have
Integer k1=new Integer(1);
Arraylist value1=new Arraylist();

originalMap.put(k1, value1);

In the clonedMap all the only key is the same instance originally created for k1. the same for the value.